# How to pass a string to screens into a BottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a BottomTabNavigator with 4 sreens inside of it, I would like to pass a string into some of them.

How can I do that ? Thank you.

```
class Main extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Developpe Inclinné',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#e8142d',
        },
    };
    render() {
        const myPath='aRouteForFirebase'
        return (
            <AppContainer myPath={myPath} />
        );
    }
}
```

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    DeveloppeInclinne,
    Chrono,
    Session, // needs the props
    Resultats // // needs the props
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better implementation:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      myPath: 'aRouteForFirebase',
    }
    this.AppContainer = createAppContainer(this.TabNavigator)
  }

  TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    DeveloppeInclinne,
    Chrono,
    Session: { screen: () => <Session myPath={this.state.myPath} />},
    Resultats { screen: () => < Resultats myPath={this.state.myPath} />}
  })

  render() {
    const { AppContainer } = this
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll try to figure out how Redux works tomorrow and include it into my project.

Comment: But don't overuse it, im working on a very big project atm and I'm trying to avoid it as much as I can because it moves the functions outside of your classes and that makes everything incomprehensible, plus you have to write more code for updating your global state.

Comment: I think you can actually run this code in production

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in react-navigation documentation which supports this. But I may be wrong. I can suggest one other way of doing it. Create a HOC and wrap your components with it. They all will have access to the common string.

```
const SomethingCommonHOC = (Component, extraProps ) => {

  return class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} {...extraProps}/>;
    }
  };
};
// Use it something like this.
SomethingCommonHOC(Session);
```

Thanks

Edit: I understand it is difficult to explain actually. That's the reason i am not big fan of HOCs. :). I will give more try to explain you the edit required.

```
Create a new file: 

Put this component definition in it:
const CommonHOC = (Component, extraProps) => {

      return class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return <Component {...this.props} {...extraProps} />;
        }
      };
    };
export default CommonHOC

Then import it in your component files , in your case DeveloppeInclinne, Chrono, Session, Resultats.
```

In component where your need to pass common string: Let's say you are editing in session component file

```
 import CommonHOC from the "path to CommonHOC"

    export default CommonHOC(Session, {
 myString: "myString"
})
```

Note: you can string like constant dynamic by converting 2nd param a the object and spreading inside the common component

Comment: can't make it work, i don't understant how i can apply this to my setup wich is much different than this. how would that translate into my BottomTabNavigator ?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, it worked in this case, but i need to re-use Session with differents paths depending on where i use it, same for Resultats, in this case i can share a common string to the both of them, but i will use those two components (Session & Resultats) with other strings(paths) depending on where i come from... so it does not solve my problem, but thank you very much for trying.

Comment: Just to give you some context, i'm building a fitness app where a user can register his performances, Session is a screen where users can register their performances, which are then stored to firebase into a specific route that as the name of the exercice. I would like to re-use the same component for all the exercices in my app by passing as a prop the name of the current exercice.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification:

```
class Main extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Developpe Inclinné',
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#e8142d',
    },
  };
  render() {
    const myPath='aRouteForFirebase'
    const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      DeveloppeInclinne,
      Chrono,
      Session: { screen: () => <Session myPath={myPath} />},
      Resultats { screen: () => < Resultats myPath={myPath} />}
    }
    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
    return (
        <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

However I don't think this is good looking code, maybe you should think about integrating Redux

Comment: It worked, why do you think it is not good code, and how would it look like with Redux ? ( i have little to no experience with Redux)

Comment: Just look up Redux in Google, that's too much to explain. I would never use this code because it creates a new TabNavigator if you change your state in the Main class, I'll post a better answer you should try aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
   DeveloppeInclinne,
   Chrono,
   Session: { screen: props => <Session {...props} />},
   Resultats { screen: props => < Resultats {...props} />}
}

// in class Session ...
console.log(this.props.myPath)
=> aRouteForFirebase
```

Comment: it returns undefined :/ (and yes i called super(props) into the constructor of Session)

Comment: I know why, the app container isn't passing down the props to the TabNavigator. You'll have to put the TabNavigator inside the render function.

Comment: react-navigation doesn't like that ... i have to put my TabNavigator into a AppContainer for it to work.